# Add handle icon to jquery resizable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a div that needs to be height resizable. Adding the resizable bar at the top was not an issue however I also need to add an icon on the left side of the gray bar so it's more obvious to the user that they can drag that.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. Setting a background to the ui-resizable-n class won't work and adding an `<img/>` tag to the generated handle, event though I can make it look right, I can't grab the icon and drag it.

Any thoughts ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/tAQbS6LYMebLGsCXPJwL?p=preview

Layout: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2227188/handle%20on%20the%20left.png (the gray bar is between 2 divs and it's resizing both of them .. that part is done - notice the icon on the left of the bray bar).

Comment: _"I also need to add an icon on the left side of the gray bar so it's more obvious to the user that they can drag that."_ Can you elaborate on that? How should the final result look?

Comment: Basically an icon on the left of the line

Comment: I could probably knock this out for you but I still don't understand what you're after. Could you put an image together?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this. I've added an image in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your screenshot, you just need to make changes in CSS to get that resize handler.

[image]

Please change the image url of handler as per your screenshot.

```
.lower .ui-resizable-n {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkiaa.png) no-repeat; 
  height: 10px;
  left: -8px; /*Adjust this value to fit it properly in the container*/
  top: -5px;
}
.lower.ui-resizable {
  border-top: 3px solid gray;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/hsPbcCunOXTyJEgby5F0?p=preview)**